# Using MVVM with Silverlight Toolkit charts

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-toolkit, caliburn.micro

I'm trying to learn MVVM with Caliburn.Micro. My exercise is to have a view represented by a page containing a chart from SIlverlight Toolkit. I have a backing ViewModel, but now I've no idea on how to bind a collection of series to a collection of ViewMode. I suppose I should have one view model for each series in my chart: am I wrong ? What should I do instead ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to check out my [Telemetry Example](http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/2012/06/creating-a-telemetry-application-using-silverlight-visiblox-and-custom-controls/) over at code project. I wrote it using Visiblox Charts, but it should still be appropriate if you have to use the Toolkit charts.

It outlines how to use the [MVVM architecture](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/silverlight/mvvm-explained.aspx) using Silverlight. The code is released under the The Code Project Open License (CPOL), so you are free to adapt it for your own purposes however you want!

Comment: Working on getting it hosted somewhere else, hopefully in a couple of days! I'll update the link then.